# Duda con el operador lógico OR (||) en c#

Tags: c#, operador

En este caso, **¿Cuál es la diferencia de usar | o usarlo doble || ?**

```
    if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) | e.KeyChar == (char)8 | e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
    {
        e.Handled = false; 
        return;
    } 
    else 
    {
       e.Handled = true; 
       return;
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Al usar operadores dobles en el caso del OR, lo que sucede es que el deja de verificar el resto de condiciones si encuentra una verdadera.

En el caso del & sucede lo mismo si encuentra una condición falsa

En su ejemplo:

```
 if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) | e.KeyChar == (char)8 | e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
```

Aqui verifica que las tres condiciones

pero:

```
 if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)8 || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
```

Si la primera condicion no se cumple, pero la segunda si, no se evalua la tercera condicion y se ingresa al "if"

Comment: Entendido, ya comprendo el funcionamiento.

Comment: Me alegra haberle ayudado

Answer (score 2):

[Segun microsoft:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator)

> La expresión que usa || evalúa solo el primer operando. La expresión
>   que usa | evalua ambos operandos.

Cuando se utiliza `|` todas las expresiones tanto izquierdas como derechas. Mientras que cuando se utiliza ||, solo se evalúa de izquierda a derecha.

---

@Sr1871 hizo referencia una respuesta de SO/ingles y hay una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3154147/3590533) que tiene una expresión que podria ayudar:

> x || y  es una expresion perezosa ya que solo `x` se evaluara, mientras
>   que  `x | y` evaluara ambas expresiones.

Comment: Solo como complemento de la respuesta sí se sabe ingles me parece que aquí hay unas respuestas muy interesantes, por si aun queda dudas
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154132/what-is-the-difference-between-logical-and-conditional-and-or-in-c

Comment: Perfecto, y muy interesante la referencia a la respuesta que comentaste, me ha quedado claro.

Answer (score 2):

Cómo ya se explicó en la respuesta aceptada, con el operador binario `|`, todas las expresiones booleanas son evaluadas.

En contraste, con el operador condicional `||`, se efectúa lo que se conoce como *evaluación "de cortocircuito"*. O sea que la evaluación de las expresiones booleanas se detiene cuando el resultado final de la evaluación ya no puede cambiar aun si se siguiera evalúando las demás expresiones.

En el ejemplo que propones, la diferencia es prácticamente nula.  Pero la diferencia es notoria con este ejemplo muy común:

```
if (obj == null || obj.Propiedad == "valor")
{
    // ...
}
```

En este caso, el uso del operador `||` permite evitar un `NullReferenceException` cuando `obj == null`, porque no se evalúa la segunda expresión en ese caso.

En contraste, si se usara el operador binario `|`:

```
if (obj == null | obj.Propiedad == "valor")
{
    // ...
}
```

...entonces si `obj == null`, vas a recibir un `NullReferenceException`.

Por esto, es muy raro que se use el operador binario `|` con expresiones booleanas. Lo más común es que se use este operador con valores enteros para efectuar un `OR` a nivel de bits.

Comment: Todas las respuestas han respondido a mi inquietud, ya me ha quedado claro cuando debo usar uno u otro :).

Comment: Este aporte es muy util, gracias